# Is Observable object released automatically RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a function that creates Observable:

```
void getData() {
   Observable.create(emitter -> {
      // call webservice
      .......
      emitter.onNext(myData);
   }).subscribe(data -> {
      // Process data here
   });
}
```

I don't want to use Disposable here. I think the observable is local variable, so it will be released after the function is done.
Is the observable released automatically after I call getData() function?

Answer (score 1):

Observable will automatically dispose they called `onComplete()` or `onError()`

Ex: You have a method to load exactly data from 10 files `Observable<String> loadFiles()` which return `Observable.create()`. Then every time you want to emit value you call `e.onNext()`, after count 10 times you will call `e.onComplete()` to mark that your Observable has finish it's work, then it will auto dispose.

You only need to call `dispose()` method to indicate that the Subscriber is **no longer interested** in any of the Observables it is currently subscribed to. Those Observables can then (if they have no other interested observers) choose to stop generating new items to emit.

Call `dispose()` when activity stopped to make sure that no more emission will come after that. So it's a good practice because it can prevent memory leaks and waste of resources, network calls.

Answer (score 0):

`Observables` do not **dispose** them-selfs.

It's a good practice to dispose your observable to avoid memory leaks and crashes of your app.

you either use `disposable.dispose()` or `compositeSubscribtion.clear()`.

I have made a simple test and after I exited the app(back btn) observable continued to emit data.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Observable.create(emitter -> {
                for (; ; ) {
                    emitter.onNext("data");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }

            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                    subscribe(data -> {
                        Log.d(tag, (String) data);

                    });

        }
    });
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
onStart() is called 
onResume() is called 
data
data
onPause() is called
onStop() is called
data 
data
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But if we don't use forever loop, is the observable released after emitter.onNext() function

Comment: I just used a forever loop and `Thread.sleep()` to simulate an expensive call.it's still running after I Exited the app.